# Remove &#13;&#13 from end of strings in list

Tags: python

I am using the following python code to extract all of the file names from a specific csv file.  It is working, but I run into a problem that the output contains two `"&#13"` at the end of each string in the list.  I am looking for a way to remove it, but am having trouble because I have to remove it from each item in the list, rather than just removing it from one string:

```
import re
import csv
import os

with open('file.txt', 'rU') as textfile:
    filetext = textfile.read()

file_list = []
file_list = [os.path.basename(fn) for fn in re.findall(r'\bFile Name:\s+.*\\.*(?=\n)', filetext)]

out_file = csv.writer(open("File-Original.csv", "wb"), delimiter='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
out_file.writerow(file_list)
```

Comment: `&#13;` looks like an HTML-entity `\n` newline to me. Something mangled your data as if it was HTML!

Comment: You need to indent your code properly

Comment: If you just want to remove `&#13` throughout, you can use `filetext = textfile.read().replace('&#13', '')`